# Sabre Error with HotelPropertyDescriptionRS PROCESSING ERROR DETECTED - L1005 ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE

Tags: sabre

When doing a HotelPropertyDescriptionRS I am getting the following error:

```xml
<stl:Message code="0">PROCESSING ERROR DETECTED - L1005</stl:Message>
<stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
```

**HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ Request:**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb='http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader'>
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type='urn:x12.org.IO5:01'><!-- credential removed --></eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type='urn:x12.org.IO5:01'>webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:ConversationId><!-- credential removed --></eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Action>
            <eb:CPAID><!-- credential removed --></eb:CPAID>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId><!-- credential removed --></eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2017-05-22T07-23-12Z</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:TimeToLive>2017-05-22T07-23-12Z</eb:TimeToLive>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext'>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username><!-- credential removed --></wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password><!-- credential removed --></wsse:Password>
                <Organization><!-- credential removed --></Organization>
                <Domain>Default</Domain>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3273412804841304188!218210!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
     <HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ xmlns='http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' Version='2.3.0'>
        <AvailRequestSegment>
            <GuestCounts Count='1' />
            <HotelSearchCriteria>
                <Criterion>
                    <HotelRef HotelCode='0034850' />
                </Criterion>
            </HotelSearchCriteria>
            <TimeSpan End='05-27' Start='05-24' />
        </AvailRequestSegment>
    </HotelPropertyDescriptionRQ>        
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

**HotelPropertyDescriptionRS Response**

```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
    <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org.IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
    </eb:From>
    <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org.IO5:01"><!-- Credential removed--></eb:PartyId>
    </eb:To>
    <eb:CPAId><!-- Credential removed--></eb:CPAId>
    <eb:ConversationId><!-- Credential removed--></eb:ConversationId>
    <eb:Service>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Service>
    <eb:Action>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRS</eb:Action>
    <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>1357732217847340150</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>2017-05-22T06:03:05</eb:Timestamp>
        <eb:RefToMessageId><!-- Credential removed--></eb:RefToMessageId>
    </eb:MessageData>
</eb:MessageHeader>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3273432471554277501!170202!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soap-env:Header>
<soap-env:Body>
    <HotelPropertyDescriptionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.3.0">
    <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
        <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-05-22T01:03:05-05:00">
            <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                <stl:Message code="0">PROCESSING ERROR DETECTED - L1005</stl:Message>
                <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
            </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Error>
    </stl:ApplicationResults>
</HotelPropertyDescriptionRS>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Comment: The same RQ is working fine for me, most likely it was a temporary issue. Are you still having issues with it?

Comment: Still getting same error.